# Google Cloud Messaging device error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I followed a tutorial about GCM Notifications located on the link below:
http://techlovejump.com/android-push-notification-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-google-play-service-library/

Everything worked fine for me, but, it works only on the emulator.
When i transfer the same apk file to mobile devices, they do not receive notifications while the same app on emulator receives them.

Is there any way i can fix this issue?

Comment: Could you post some code ?

Comment: are you using signed apk

Comment: Another thing, are you sure you have the right permissions for c2dm ?
Could you post that your manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I see that this can happen is when the ***registration_ID is changed***. When this happens the device which is supposed to receive the notification as per the expectations does not receives it because the registration_ID is tied to a different device and account.

Make sure you have a distinct registration_ID for the new test device. And even if the versions of Android OS are different on both you need to re-register. Also you need to check that the Registration_ID is getting refreshed everytime in the *Broadcast receiver* Bundle when it receives a new Registration_ID from Google.

Since [gcm.register()](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/legacy-regid) is deprecated make use of the new concept ***[Instance_ID](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/)*** by Google.